# Rails not found after installing via rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu-13.10

I've installed rails via rvm following  [this blog](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/).

Once installed it showed rails installed. But when i open a new terminal rails [Its not found]

```
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages,...
```

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

what should i do to add it?

rvm list:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

ruby -v

```
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
```

rvm gemset list

```
gemsets for ruby-2.1.0 (found in /home/dinesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0)
=> (default)
   global
```

Comment: provide output of `rvm list`, `ruby -v`, `rvm gemset list`

Comment: Do you have multiple ruby versions installed, and is rails installed for a non-default ruby version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This loads rvm each time you load a new terminal session.

Comment: do i need to add this in /home/user/.bashrc ? (when i enter !/.bahsrc it makes it as /home/user/.bashrc)

Comment: Yea exactly. I suppose you installed rvm as root user.

Answer (score 1):

Close out your current shell or terminal session and open a new one (preferred). You may load RVM with the following command:

```
user$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

If installation and configuration were successful, RVM should now load whenever you open a new shell. This can be tested by executing the following command which should output 'rvm is a function' as shown below.

```
user$ type rvm | head -n 1
rvm is a function
```

source: http://rvm.io/rvm/install

If you are using GNOME on Red Hat, CentOS or Fedora, ensure that the Run command as login shell option is checked under the Title and Command tab in Profile Preferences(right click on terminal go to profile preferences). After changing this setting, you may need to exit your console session and start a new one before the changes take affect.

Comment: @Dineshkumar what was the response when you added the line in my posting to your bashrc?

Comment: @theAreba: It Worked. [Accepted Answer] (whats it do? help for beginner like me!)

Comment: @Dineshkumar it automatically loads rvm each time you create a new terminal session i.e each time you open up a new terminal. This simplifies what Rahul said since it would have required you to type $ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm each time you loaded a new terminal. Do you get the point?